# JavaScript Array Object Multi Level Search Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I want to search in JavaScript multi-level array object.

[{
    "head": "Heading 1",
    "list": [ {
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    },{
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    }]
},{
    "head": "Heading 2",
    "list": [ {
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    },{
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    }]
}]

If we search for "Heading 2"

Expected Result :

[{
    "head": "Heading 2",
    "list": [ {
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    },{
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    }]
}]

If we search for "name 1"

Expected Result :

[{
    "head": "Heading 1",
    "list": [ {
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    },{
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    }]
},{
    "head": "Heading 2",
    "list": [ {
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    },{
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1"
    }]
}]

Looking for an optimized way to do this search. Can anyone help me with this problem?

**UPDATED**: Invalid JSON Format

Comment: please add what you have tried, and what does not work. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: That's not a valid json..

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: I updated the JSON to Valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an recursive search for the wanted value of a nested value of a given object.

```js
function filter(array, value) {
    function find(object) {
        return Object
            .values(object)
            .some(v => v === value || v && typeof v === 'object' && find(v));
    }

    return array.filter(find);
}

var array = [{ head: "Heading 1", list: [{ name: "name 1", desc: "desc 1" }, { name: "name 1", desc: "desc 1" }] }, { head: "Heading 2", list: [{ name: "name 1", desc: "desc 1" }, { name: "name 1", desc: "desc 1" }] }]

console.log(filter(array, "Heading 2"));
console.log(filter(array, "name 1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```